# Center and hide overflow of WP toolbar custom links

Tags: plugins, php, menus, admin-bar

I have made 22 custom links in the WP toolbar for my site but when I reduce browser/screen width they are completely un-resposnive in terms of CSS and stack instead of simply not displaying links that do not fit.

Ie, I want to apply margin:center and overflow:hidden to all of them together so they are in the center of the toolbar and any that do not fit on different window sizes will be hidden.

Would be practically impossible to include all the code here but I hope these examples show what I have and havnt done.

I have tried both the class and ID CSS but nothing is effecting the links.

```
.quicklinksgroup {
    margin: auto !important;
    width: 1600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#classquicklinks {
    margin: auto !important;
    width: 1600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How I generate the group and parent nodes in the custom plugin I made. I have 22 of these looped to create the custom menus drop down. White each there is also child nodes but I didnt think you would need to see them as they are practically the same and working fine. As you can see I have also tried the CSS, that I think should be right, inline.

```
function add_nodes_and_groups_to_toolbar( $wp_admin_bar ) {

args = array(
        'id'    => 'quicklinksgroup',
'title' => '<div id="quicklinksgroupcontainer" style="margin:auto!important;
width: 1600px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 100px;" ></div>',
'meta'   => array( 'class' => 'classquicklinksgroup' )
    );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_group( $args );



    $args = array(
    'id'    => 'parent_node'.$Number.'',
    'title' => '<div id="linkbutton" style="margin-top:2px text-align:center;"><img src="http://example.com/'.$IMG.'" alt="'.$TEXT.'" style="width:40px;height:25px;"></div>',
            'href'  => '/page/'.$Live.'',
            //'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'OnlineQuickLinks' )
            'parent' => 'quicklinks'
        );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
```

I know I am not an expert at asking questions here but if we find a solution will be very helpful to me and others as I really couldnt see anything on the search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: hidden;` to your CSS for #wpadminbar.

Add this to your CSS:

```
#wpadminbar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but wont that be for everything in the tool bar? There is also all the original Wordpress stuff in it. Like the WP logo etc.

Comment: Yes, but it should still work as expected. If you shrink your browser after applying this CSS you will see that anything that overflows on the right will be hidden. This will not clip anything of WordPress off and you should be fine. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: It's also good to note that if the page shrinks too much it will turn to a mobile version, thus never allowing it to clip any of the original links. So with this code you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this for now but it would of been nicer to group the custom links in question together in a div container that I can center and hidden the overflow of.

Comment: I'll see if I can work something out and edit this post if I find anything. But for the time being could you accept and vote up my post?

Comment: I cant sorry. Its against the rules here. Its not a correct solution. Not only does it not center the grouped custom links like asked, it also breaks the child drop-downs. If you can find a proper solution I would be happy to mark this as the correct answer. Thanks for your time and the lead you did give.

Comment: Sorry, I was caught up today. Will definitely start working on a solution. Thanks for checking this out. Will get working on it now. Cheers :D!